# It is possible to get make array in cell from another tables result in mysql

Tags: mysql

I Have two table and i have get result from both of table 
Here is the table

```
        Table1      
+-------------------+   
|   APH |   ID      |
+-------------------+   
|   A   |   ID01    |
|   B   |   ID02    |
|   C   |   ID03    |
|   D   |   ID04    |
+-------------------+   

        Table2  
+-------------------+   
|   ID      | Value |
+-------------------+
|   ID01    |   10  |
|   ID01    |   15  |
|   ID01    |   20  |
|   ID01    |   25  |
|   ID02    |   6   |
|   ID02    |   18  |
|   ID02    |   30  |
|   ID02    |   42  |
|   ID02    |   54  |
|   ID03    |   7   |
|   ID03    |   15  |
|   ID03    |   23  |
|   ID03    |   31  |
+-------------------+
```

**For Example:-**

I have to get all value from table where ID = ID01

so is it possible to get result like this.?

```
        Result      
+-----------------------------------+
|   APH |   ID      |   Value       |
+-----------------------------------+
|   A   |   ID01    |[10,15,20,25]  |
+-----------------------------------+
```

And For All Result

```
        Result      
+-----------------------------------+
|   APH |   ID0     |   Value       |
+-----------------------------------+
|   A   |   ID01    |[10,15,20,25]  |
|   B   |   ID02    |[6,18,30,42,54]|
|   C   |   ID03    |[7,15,23,31]   |
|   D   |   ID04    |               |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP_CONCAT`

> MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT()` function returns a string with concatenated
>   `non-NULL` value from a group.
>
> Returns `NULL` when there are no `non-NULL` values.

```
SELECT 
 APH,
 ID,
 CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(T2.`value`),']') AS output
FROM Table1 AS T1 
INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.ID ='ID01'
```

**EDIT:**

Just leave the `CONCAT` part if you only want comma separated list.

```
SELECT 
 APH,
 ID,
 GROUP_CONCAT(T2.`value`) AS output
FROM Table1 AS T1 
INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.ID ='ID01'
```

**EDIT2:**

```
SELECT 
 APH,
 ID,
 GROUP_CONCAT(T2.`value`) AS output
FROM Table1 AS T1 
INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
GROUP BY T1.ID;
```

Comment: Hello sir need one more help 
how to make this `$Array = '[10,15,20,25]'` in array because it is showing string;

Comment: Are you using php?

Comment: Yes i am using php

Comment: Then just use `GROUP_CONCAT(T2.`value`)`. Then you can convert the comma separated values in an array I guess. I don't know php :(

Comment: May be `explode` function in php can do it.

Comment: That can do i am working on it Thanks a lot @1000111

Comment: this is not working i want all result without a particular Id

Comment: **this is not working!!** Instead say that I need result for all ID. :)

Comment: Please check the updated answer under **EDIT2** section.

Comment: in case data is not in value column then it wont give result is there any option to show this blank or null in the cell have a look on the All Result table

Comment: use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: It is not working do i need to change something else in this 
`SELECT 
 APH,
 ID,
 GROUP_CONCAT(T2.`value`) AS output
FROM Table1 AS T1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
GROUP BY T1.ID;`

Comment: Done There is "where" condition so i changed it

Comment: Hi Again can you help me out what is difference between [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B74WYUnqb4GcMzdRWks1OE9heVU) two data base

Answer (score 0):

I believe this helps you get what you desire

```
Select 
    t1.APH,t1.ID Group_Concat(t2.Value) Over (Partition By t1.ID) As Value
From 
    Table1 t1 
Inner Join 
    Table2 t2 on tr.ID=t2.ID
Where
    t1.ID = 'ID01'
```